# rtorrent execute shell script

Tags: bash, shell, libtorrent

I can't figure out how to get output from shell script back to rtorrent after command has been executed.
Is it possible to return back output from exeternal command back to rtorrent session?
I use rtorrent scripting interface to auto execute shell command after torrent is finished
event line in .rtorrent.rc looks like this:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,mycustomcommand,"execute=~/myshellscript.sh"
```

myshellscript.sh file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Torrent finished!"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add parameters to the rtorrent.rc itself and also the bash script is incomplete according to me.

.rtorrent.rc line should have

```
method.set_key = event.download.finished,whatever,"execute2={/path/myscript.sh,$d.name=,$d.base_path=,$d.hash=}"
```

bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TORRENT_NAME=1
TORRENT_PATH=2
TORRENT_HASH=3

touch "$1" Finished download!

exit
```

this will create touch file telling you particular file has finished downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're searching for, but I found this on [rtorrent's wiki site](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/RtorrentScripting#rTorrent_scripting_basics):

> `execute_capture_nothrow={command,arg1,arg2,...}`
>
> This will execute the external command with arguments arg1,arg2,.... It will return the
> stdout output of the command.

Comment: I've tried this before, but still no luck. execute_capture_nothrow={command,arg1,arg2,...}This will execute the external command with arguments arg1,arg2,.... It will return the stdout output of the command. I've even tried this one, but still no luck. Maybe its something to do with screen session.

Comment: What is the goal exactly? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to execute shell script and return back output (stdout) back to rtorrent

Comment: Ok, but what would rtorrent do with that?

Comment: I run script from within rtorrent through rtorrent scripting interface. so that's must say something. I'm starting to doubt that its possible to do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,mycustomcommand,print="$execute_capture=/path/to/script"
```

should work, at least

```
print="$execute_capture=/path/to/script"
```

works when you do it inside rtorrent. If you want to store the output then intstead of print use d.custom1.set= if that helps.